# Requery of subform returns “#Deleted” in all fields on the second selection

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am having a problem with requery where it works fine on the first selection but returns "#Deleted" in every field on the form if another record is selected.

I have a main form `frm_Manage_Demand` with two subforms: 1) `frm_Pick_Part_Number_List` which contains a listbox and 2) `frm_Manage_Demand_Sub` which contains a number of attributes for a selected part number.  The desired behavior is that when a user selects a part number then data on the second form is updated.

I have two tables: the first is `tbl_usage_price_cost` which contains data for 30k part numbers.  The second is `tbl_Manage_Demand` which contain records for select part numbers that is copied from `tbl_usage_price_cost` that the user has selected for further processing.  I use the field, `QUOTE_ID_FK = -1` to identify the part number record that the user has selected.  Every time the user clicks on a new part number in form 1 I delete this record and create a new one with the data associated with the selected part number.  This code works fine.

The `recordsource` for `frm_Manage_Demand_Sub` is `"SELECT * FROM tbl_Manage_Demand WHERE QUOTE_ID_FK = -1"`

The problem comes when the user clicks on a second part number after successfully selecting an initial part number.

Here is the code in the `frm_Manage_Demand` procedure that causes the `frm_Manage_Demand_Sub` to show "#Deleted" on the `frm_Manage_Demand_Sub` form on the second pass:

```
With frm_Manage_Demand_Sub.Form
        .RecordSource = "SELECT * FROM tbl_Manage_Demand WHERE QUOTE_ID_FK = -1"
        .Requery
End With
```

Here are some of things I have tried:

`Setfocus` to the frm_Manage_Demand_Sub form.
Reset the `recordset` each time.  I have replaced the above code with:

```
Me!frm_Manage_Demand_Sub.Form.RecordSource = "SELECT * FROM tbl_Manage_Demand WHERE QUOTE_ID_FK = -1"
Me!frm_Manage_Demand_Sub.Form.Requery
```

This has the same error.

Any assistance is sincerely appreciated.

Comment: Not really understanding requirement to routinely delete record. Why set RecordSource since the SQL statement is unchanged? Is subform Master/Child Links set? When record is deleted on main form, cascade delete removes dependent records? Perhaps should requery main form.

Comment: The main `form frm_Manage_Demand` has no recordsource only the sub form `frm_Manage_Demand_Sub`.  The reason for deleting the record with `QUOTE_ID_FK = - 1` is that I need a container for the selected part number and its associated data for when the user decides to proceed to the next step....the user decides to enter quotes from vendors....then I create a Quote record and then associate the `Quote ID1` in the Quote table with the `QUOTE_ID_FK` in the `tbl_Manage_Demand` table.  I do this because I allow the user to change some of the demand data associated with a part number.